# Wagtail 2.11 loads old Jquery version

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

So I upgraded wagtail on my production server, and for some reason jquery on my production server is 3.2.1
[image]

But on my local server it's as needed 3.5.1
[image]

Ran `collectstatic`, `collectstatic --clear`, cleared the cache, reinstalled wagtail, nothing worked...

How can I fix that?

Comment: Are you sure your production server is running Wagtail 2.11? What does the version number at the bottom of the Settings menu say?

Comment: @gasman, of course... Didn't check that because couldn't open settings menu... Checked it in DevTools, 2.9.3... I was sure it was 2.11 because Pipenv and Pip showed 2.11. Can you please answer the question so I mark it solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @gasman, I didn't check the actual version of Wagtail. I realized that Wagtail on production server was in a different virtual environment than the ones I checked.